# Duplicate variable is not detected as duplicate after compilation

Tags: apex, static, variable

Definining 2 class variables with same name does not always fire `Duplicate field` compilation error when deploying apex class to the org.

Code sample :

```
public with sharing class MyClass {
    Boolean hasData;
    static Boolean hasData = false; //this is allowed because static ?
}
```

From above code, removing `static` from 2nd variable then fires `Duplicate field: hasData` after deploying to org.

Any documented explanation why we have this behaviour ?

Comment: I imagine that one of them being static means that there's no ambugity when the parser/compiler works through it. It's able to distinguish between a "Class" token and an "variable of type [Class]" token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a duplicate variable. You are allowed to have a static variable and an instance variable of the same name. They are in a different scope. You can, in fact, have up to three variables with the same name inside the same function:

```
public class MyClass {
  public Boolean hasData;
  public static Boolean hasData = false;
  public void myMethod() {
    Boolean hasData = true;
    System.debug(hasData); // true
    System.debug(this.hasData); // null
    System.debug(MyClass.hasData); // false
  }
}
```

Note that [Name Shadowing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_name_shadowing.htm) rules apply here. You can see how I can progressively choose from the local scope (no prefix), the local instance (`this`), and the static scope (`MyClass`).

As a best practice, I would avoid doing this in your code, as it can be frustrating to debug, especially if the variable and the method using that variable are far away from each other (you might not realize what you've done), but it is certainly possible. Note that function parameters and local variables share the same scope, so you cannot define a variable with the same name as a parameter:

```
public void myMethod(Boolean hasData) {
  Boolean hasData; // Does not compile
}
```

However, you can also create a temporary scope in a code block:

```
public void myMethod() {
  {
     Boolean hasData = true;
     System.debug(hasData); // true
  }
  {
     Boolean hasData = false; 
     System.debug(hasData); // false
  }
}
```

Normally, these temporary blocks are used for do-while, while, for, and if statements, but unconditional blocks are also legal.

Comment: @sdfcfox thanks a lot for such high quality answer